# How do we find the sum of this series $\sum [a+(n-1)d] b r^{n-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Let $a, b, d, r$ be real numbers such that $d \neq 0$ and  $r \neq 0$. Let $$s_n \colon= [a+ (n-1)d] b r^{n-1}$$ for $n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Then how do we find $$\sum_{n=1}^N s_n$$ for $N = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$?

Are there any values of $a, b, d, r$ for which the series $\sum s_n$ converges?

Are there any values of $a, b, d, r$ for which the series converges absolutely?

Comment: Just expand the summation term. Then you are left with $\Sigma n r^{n-1}$ and $\Sigma r^{n-1}$

Comment: Each having a closed form

Comment: This is an example of an arithmetic-geometric series (AGP)....its sum can easily be obtained by performing the 'shift and subtract' operation on the entire series twice.

Answer (score 2):

HINT You can start by writing it as $$(a-d)b\sum_{n=1}^Nr^{n-1}+db\sum_{n=1}^Nnr^{n-1}$$

the first sum is a geometric series and the second is the derivative of a geometric series

Comment: so we have the following calculation: $$\sum_{n=1}^N s_n = (a-d)b\sum_{n=1}^Nr^{n-1}+db\sum_{n=1}^Nnr^{n-1} = (a-d)b \frac{r(1-r^N)}{1-r} + db \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} r } \sum_{n=1}^N r^n =  (a-d)b \frac{r(1-r^N)}{1-r} + db \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} r } \left( \frac{r- r^{{N+1} }{1-r} \right) =  (a-d)b \frac{r(1-r^N)}{1-r} + db \frac{ [1-(N+1)r^N] (1-r) + r-r^{N+1} }{(1-r)^2} =  (a-d)b \frac{r(1-r^N)}{1-r} + db \frac{ 2 - (N+1)r^N - (N+2)r^{N+1} }{(1-r)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Based on David Quinn's hint:

Provided $r \neq 1$, we have the following calculation: $$\sum_{n=1}^N s_n = (a-d)b \sum_{n=1}^N r^{n-1} + db \sum_{n=1}^N nr^{n-1} = (a-d)b \frac{1-r^N}{1-r} + db \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} r } \sum_{n=1}^N r^n =  (a-d)b \frac{1-r^N}{1-r} + db \frac{ \mathrm{d} }{ \mathrm{d} r } \left( \frac{r- r^{ N+1 } }{1-r} \right) =  (a-d)b \frac{ 1-r^N }{1-r} + db \frac{ [1-(N+1)r^N] (1-r) + r-r^{ N+1 } }{ (1-r)^2 } =  (a-d)b \frac{ 1-r^N }{1-r} + db \frac{ 1 - (N+1)r^N + N r^{N+1} }{(1-r)^2} = \frac{ (a-d)b (1-r) (1-r^N) + db [ 1 - (N+1)r^N + N r^{N+1} ] }{ (1-r)^2} = \frac{ a( 1 - r - r^N + r^{N+1} ) - db [ 1 - r - r^N + r^{N+1} - ( 1 - (N+1)r^N + N r^{N+1} ) ]  }{ (1-r)^2} = \frac{ a( 1 - r - r^N + r^{N+1} ) - db [  - r + N r^N  - (N-1) r^{N+1} ]  }{ (1-r)^2} = \frac{ a( 1 - r - r^N + r^{N+1} ) + dbr [  1 -  N r^{N-1}  + (N-1) r^N ]  }{ (1-r)^2} .$$

But how do we answer the remaining questions in my post?

Comment: You should add this as an addendum to your original post, as it informs the reader that the original question has moved on to another (albeit) related question.

Answer (score 0):

you can break $$\sum_{n=1}^N s_n$$ as ab$\sum_{n=1}^N r^{n-1}$ +bd$\sum_{n=1}^N (n-1)r^{n-1}$

you can find the geometric sum $\sum r^{n-1}$....now you take k=$\sum_{n=1}^N (n-1)r^{n-1}$

see k-rk= $ r+r^2+r^3+r^4+..........+r^{N-2}$+(N-1)$r^N$=k(1-r)

now k=$\frac{r(1-r^{N-2})}{(1-r)^2}$ +$\frac{(N-1)r^N}{1-r}$

provided r is not 1

if r=1 then $s_n$ becomes ap series.